# Save Visible WMS layer to file

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, qgis-plugins

Is there tool to save currently visible WMS layer to file in QGIS, or some place in QGIS where you can get needed xml to fetch it using gdal ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always save the current view as georeferenced image, and use that with gdal. Although it is only screen resolution and size, maybe not what you want.

Alternatively, you can input WMS data directly:
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html
You may find the used parameters of the connection in the .qgs file.

Comment: Did not know that. Go File, save as Picture, and it actually makes georeferenced picture from it. Thank you.
It solves problem for now.

Comment: Sorry, it's not so clear for me. Someway I can save georeferenced image from wms source? I save the .qgs file, what should I do after?

Comment: The linked page describes how to setup a local xml file for the wms service, and how to use gdal_translate to convert the WMS response to a raster file. For the WMS parameters, look into the .qgs file.